# Can not add API Integration key under my DocuSign account

Tags: docusignapi

I have created a free DocuSign account , to test the integration with our application. but when i wen to Admin >> API & Keys, i can not find any option to add the API key, here is what i got:-

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Integration Keys are created in the developer sandbox system, demo.docusign.net.

You can obtain a free developer account by visiting [developers.docusign.com](https://developers.docusign.com). See the button in the upper right corner.

After you've developed your application, you use the go-live procedure to have your integration key made available for the production systems. To do so, you will need a paid DocuSign account.

Comment: @Larryk I want you little help. I am having a paid account but still there is no option to add integration key. can you please tell why?

Comment: @amitgupta -- please see my answer. Integration Keys are only created in the developer system. They are then copied over to the production system after you complete the go-live process

Comment: @LarryK The problem is I am very new to docusign. I have a standard account and there is no option to generate integration keys. I have a general scenario that i just want to hit api for creating an envelope using a template. So, for this how can i pass a go live process if my motive to run just apis simply through postman? can you please help?

Comment: @amitgupta I suggest you attend an API office hours webinar. See https://www.docusign.com/resources or ask new questions on stackoverflow.

Comment: @LarryK ok, thankyou I have published the question on stackoverflow.